# Simple c prog. error: invalid type arguement of unary '*'

Tags: c, matrix

this is my first post here and I'm very new to C.

I want to write a program that is able to print matrixes. It should look like:

```
----
-o--
ooo-
----
```

So i want that to be printed for the beginning.

My current code is:

```
    // 4. Exercise
// Learn 2d arrays

#include <stdio.h>

char z;
char s;
char m1_ptr;


void createMatrix()
{
  for(z = 0; z != 4; z++)
  {
    for (s = 0; s != 4; s++)
    {
      printf("%c", *m1_ptr);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

}



//------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{

  char o = o;
  char c = '-';
  // And some variables for the matrix count:
  char matrix_1 [4][4] ={{c,c,c,c},{c,o,c,c},{o,o,o,c},{c,c,c,c}};
  char *m1_ptr = &matrix_1 [z][s];

  createMatrix(matrix_1 [0][0]);



/* for(z = 0; z != 4; z++)
  {
    for (s = 0; s != 4; s++)
    {
      printf("%c", matrix_1 [z][s]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
*/
  return 0;

}
```

It works if I put the void function into the main, but since there are much more matrixes coming I want to do that in an extra function to make it more readable.

If I compile that I get the error message:

"Line17: Error: invalid type argument of unary '*' ('have int')"
(edit: line 17 is where it says "printf("c......")

I looked at other questions, but since I only understand super simple programs yet that didn't work out for me.

Does anyone know how that could be fixed?
(It would be nice if the answer explains why, since I have very little experience with pointers)

Comment: Your example doesn't makes sence how the pattern should look like! Also sry but your code looks horibble. Just explain how the pattern should look like

Comment: That's an exercice we have to do at school. It's that I have to print 4 Matrixes on the screen (that's why matrix"_1") and rotate them 4 times for 90° each. it's no practical use and i understand that doesn t make much sense, for the sake of learning.  So the thing that might change between the different matrixes is that the c and o s in char matrix_n [4][4] might be switched. Do you know what I mean?

And sorry about the readability, I'm really unexperienced yet.

Comment: Oh, that suckes. If I delte the global    <code>char m1_ptr;</code>    then i get the error that    m1_ptr    is undeclared(line17 too).

Comment: this kind of for statement: for(z = 0; z != 4; z++) should be written as: for(z = 0; z < 4; z++)  because the loop will stop at 4 or higher, a much safer test condition than z != 4

Comment: Thanks for the tipp, i'll change that.

Comment: @Yíu you only have to print that pattern?

Comment: this line: char m1_ptr; at the beginning of the code, defines a single char with name m1_ptr.  That variable is then being 'shadowed' in the function:  main()  The compiler should have issued a warning about that.  in general, NEVER ignore warnings.

Comment: this line: void createMatrix() indicates (due to no prototype) that there can be parameters, but they are not specifically defined.  The line should be:  void createMatrix( char *pMatrix )  Note: the actual parameter name is somewhat arbitrary, but should be meaningful, as in this case meaning pointer to matrix

Comment: @Yíu I think you looking for something like my answer! updated it so it's a function and you can print 2d matrix's with this

Comment: this line: printf("%c", *m1_ptr); will cause a seg fault because the visible m1_ptr is a single char, not a pointer that has been pointed to something.

Comment: I would, for flexability in the createMatrix() function have a second and third parameter.  Where those parameters would be the number of rows and number of columns for the matrix to be created.

Comment: regarding this function: void createMatrix(), it is NOT creating a matrix, rather it is walking through a (in this case non-existant) matrix and displaying the contents on the terminal.  suggest a more descriptive name, (and remember to all the needed 3 parameters.

Comment: @user3829249 codeblocks doesn t warn me about that. thanks for all the comments here.

Comment: it not a good idea to be using the global variables s, z for your local 'for' loop indexes.

Comment: Regarding the global and local variables I guess I think wrong. What I think is: when i state a global variable it allows me to modify that variable in my main and then it is in the memory for the whole main function, and since im jumping from my main to the void function and then come back to my main it should still be in the memory modified. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your looking for something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROW 4
#define COLUMN 4

void printMatrix(int rowLength, int columnLength, char matrix[rowLength][columnLength]) {

    int rowCount, columnCount;

    for(rowCount = 0; rowCount < rowLength; rowCount++) {

        for(columnCount = 0; columnCount < columnLength; columnCount++)
            printf("%c", matrix[rowCount][columnCount]);

        printf("\n");
    }


}


int main() {

    char o = 'o';
    char c = '-';
    char matrix_1 [ROW][COLUMN] = {
                            {c,c,c,c},
                            {c,o,c,c},
                            {o,o,o,c},
                            {c,c,c,c}
                           };

    printMatrix(ROW, COLUMN, matrix_1);


    return 0;

}
```

It prints the pattern you want

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for and it solves all the mentioned problems! And it is much more readable than mine and good to understand. Thanks for the fast help,I really appreciate. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>


void displayMatrix( char pMatrix[rCount][cCount], int rCount, int cCount )
{

    for(int i = 0; i < rCount; i++ ) // one loop for each row
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cCount; j++) // one loop for each column
        {
            printf("%c", pMatrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n"); // prep for next row
    }
}



//------------------------------------------------------------------
static const o = 'o';
static const c = '-';

int main()
{
     // And some variables for the matrix count:
     char matrix_1 [][] ={{c,c,c,c},{c,o,c,c},{o,o,o,c},{c,c,c,c}};

     displayMatrix(matrix_1, 
                   sizeof( matrix_1) / sizeof(matrix_1[0]),  // = number of rows
                   sizeof( matrix_1[0]) );                   // = number of columns

     return 0;

}
```